# System.Threading.Timer does not work correctly

Tags: c#, timer

I notice the timer is not correct.

This is a very simple C# code: it will print current date/time every 1 minute. 
My expected result is: let it run at 3:30 PM then we will have: 3:31 PM, 3:32 PM, 3:33 PM, ...

But sometime don't receive above result: sometime it is 3:31 PM, 3:32 PM, 3:34 PM, ...

So it lost 1 row.

Could anyone point me what is problem?

```
class Program
{
    static Timer m_Timer;
    static int countDown;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        countDown = 60; 
        m_Timer = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 1000);

        while (true) { System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); };
    }

    static void TimerCallback(Object o)
    {
        countDown -= 1; 
        if (countDown <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" ===>>>>>" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
            countDown = 60;
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); //long running code demo
    }
}
```

Comment: You could output debug statements to get behind on what's actually going on.

Comment: My real purpose is finding a way to call my codes/function in exact every x seconds. For example I will write a record into database ....

Comment: Dear All,
I changed to use this new way: calculate the time different . Looks like it works ok

static void TimerCallback(Object o)
        {
            if((DateTime.Now- lastRun).TotalSeconds >= CHECK_POINT)
            {
                lastRun = DateTime.Now;
                Console.WriteLine(" ===>>>>>" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }
            
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); //long running code demo
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just post what found here for people that have problem like me.
I found the answer from another thread.
I use "HighResolutionTimer.cs" and it works perfect:
https://gist.github.com/DraTeots/436019368d32007284f8a12f1ba0f545

Comment: It makes sense. Previous timer used a thread pool is much lower limits as max number of threads. But. Suggestion in this case would be to monitor CPU and RAM usage on the machine. If you have too many threads doing heavy jobs schedule is one things but to make sure they complete successfully and have resources is another.

Answer (score 2):

System.Threading.Timer runs on threads from thread pool. You run callback function which runs on one thread in pool every 1s and block it for 10s using sleep. Depending on how many threads you have in thread pool at some timepoints they all may be blocked and wait or .NET should allocate new thread up to the maximum of threads in pool for you.

---

From comments extended answer.

> Each function is independent and it does not wait until another processing finish. A simple task is: call a function to do something every 1 minutes. "do something" in my case is saving local variables into SQL server. This process is fast not slow. I use 1 timer for many functions because each function is schedule in different cycle. For example, function 1 is triggered every 1 minute, function 2 is triggered every 10 seconds ... That why I use the timer 1 second.

Your use case seems to be more complex as I read it from initial question. You have different tasks and try to implement sort of scheduler. Maybe each particular tasks is fast but all together some runs may be longer and blocking. Not sure how this logic was well implemented but there could be a lot of edge cases e.g. some run was missed etc.

How I would approach it?

1. I would not try to implement on my own if scheduler can be more complex. I would pick ready solution, e.g. [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net). They consider edge cases and help to scale on cluster with needed and help with config.
2. In any case I would refactor bigger schedule to have each task to run on its schedule based on configuration (custom implementation or Quartz) as smaller tasks
3. I would scale your "queue" of tasks first locally by introducing some queue, for example using ConcurrentQueue or [BlockingCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview) or any produce-consumer to limit number of threads and if performance of such execution is not good scale on cluster. By doing so you can at least guarantee that N tasks can be scheduled and executed locally and everything beyond is queued. Maybe having some priorities for tasks can also help because there might be execution which could be missed but there are execution which must run on schedule.

I doubt it is a good idea to start from thread timer execution other threads or tasks if most likely you already have problems with threading.

You problem is not with System.Threading.Timer, it does its job well. Your use case is more complex.

Comment: So is there a way we can ensure to run codes in exact every x minutes?

Comment: The problem is not in running code exactly every X minutes. .NET runtime actually tries to execute your code on schedule. The problem is in long running code. Solution would be optimise it or split it. Why you need schedule every 1s operation that takes 10s, could it be splited that it takes 1 s? Could you please let me know more about what logic is executed so long? How each execution depends from each other or they are independent? Do you need to wait until its finished? Is queue any option to schedule or check processing each second but wait until processing is finished and start new?

Comment: Each function is dependent and it does not wait until another processing finish. A simple task is: call a function to do something every 1 minutes.
"do something" in my case is saving local variables into SQL server. This process is fast not slow.

I use 1 timer for many functions because each function is schedule in different cycle. For example, function 1 is triggered every 1 minute, function 2 is triggered every 10 seconds ...

That why I use the timer 1 second.

Comment: @Leh I have updated answer based on your comment. Please review and let me know your feedback

Comment: Thank you. I will study your suggestion. But I run my simple codes that I posted above and it is still wrong. That codes are very simple. I just want to find a way that call my function at specific time.

In my real application, the tool must write 1440 (24hours * 60minutes)  records in a day (1 record every 1 minute) into SQL table but I faced a problem if losing some record, usually about 5-10 records/day for 1 table.

Comment: Your simple code use all threads in pool. It is nor right way for such use case. Also it is not illustrating your problem. You need to use other approaches as suggested using scheduler wich handling of missed runs or some streaming solution like Kafka. Basically you need a persistence queue on which you will run your tasks on schedule. And again it is first impression overall use case description is important in this case. But IMO you won't solve your problem simply by using timer or scheduled execution

Answer (score 1):

Windows - is not real time operating system. So, if you expect that timer waits ecactly 1 second - it's wrong. There are many reasonsm when timer can wait more time. Because of [timer resolution](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/) or other high load operations.

Comment: Thank you for your link. I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

The above code causes, that every second you run 10-second "demo" (sleep). You will run 10 worker threads simultanously.

Are you sure, this is what you are trying to achieve?

To see what really happens in your app, simply add:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Time:{DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt")},Thread:{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId},countDown:{countDown}");
```

in the beginning of TimerCallback. You will notice, that timespan between following callbacks are not exactly 1000ms (usually it is a *little bit* more). This is perfectly normal in non-rtc OS, and, in most cases - it's not a problem. Just keep in mind, that Timer is not exact.

Moreover, if you are trying to use Timer that way, and trying to count ticks - these *little errors* cumulates in following ticks.

Comment: Thank you. My codes are just a demo but I am using this method in real application. What I want is perform an action every x second, for example: checking something and save data into SQL server. In this example, I want exact 1 record every 60 seconds (1 minutes).

So if Timer is not correct then is there a way I can get my codes run in exact every x seconds?

Comment: If you want to do action every 60 second, why don't you set timer for 60 seconds? In vast majority of cases, error won't be larger than tens of miliseconds. In solution, that you provided, this error is multiplied by 60 (it cumulates with every tick).

Comment: Good question but the timer is used to call many function: so function A is called every 10 seconds, function B is called every 20 seconds ....
That why i use only 1 timer.

Answer (score 0):

If you like newer .NET TPL syntax yo can write it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Repeat(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void Repeat(TimeSpan period)
        {
            Task.Delay(period)
                .ContinueWith(
                    t =>
                    {
                            //Do your staff here
                            Console.WriteLine($"Time:{DateTime.Now}");
                        Repeat(period);
                    });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you. so your idea is using delay will solve problem?

Comment: You can try check it and let me know . We have used similar type of code to execute particular operation for each interval